# Nx Daemon stops working when using custom remote cache

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Whenever I build my Angular application with my custom task runner that uses a custom remote cache, the Nx daemon stops working. A commit, like you often read, does not solve the issue. I suspect that my custom remote cache implementation of the store method might have issues:

```
store = async (hash: string, cacheDirectory: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    console.debug('writing in cache...');
    console.debug(`hash: ${hash}`);
    const hashCommit = hash + '.commit';
    const localCommit = path.join(cacheDirectory, hashCommit);
    const local = path.join(cacheDirectory, hash);
    const zipped = zip(local);

    const blobContainer = getBlobContainer(
      this.connectionString,
      this.container
    );

    const remote = blobContainer.getBlockBlobClient(`${hash}.zip`);
    const remoteCommit = blobContainer.getBlockBlobClient(hashCommit);

    await remote.uploadData(zipped);
    await remoteCommit.uploadFile(localCommit);

    return Promise.resolve(true);
  };
```

> NX   Failed to start or connect to the Nx Daemon process.
>
> Messages from the log:    [NX Daemon Server] -
> 2022-12-24T22:56:35.583Z - [REQUEST]: Client Request for Project Graph
> Received    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:35.635Z - [REQUEST]:
> Updated file-hasher based on watched changes, recomputing project
> graph...    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:36.541Z - Started
> listening on:
> \.\pipe\nx\C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Temp\78c4dcdc4cfc72d78c62\d.sock
> [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.033Z - Established a
> connection. Number of open connections: 1    [NX Daemon Server] -
> 2022-12-24T22:56:37.034Z - Established a connection. Number of open
> connections: 2    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.035Z -
> [WATCHER]: Subscribed to changes within:
> c:\Users\stefa\Local_Storage\projects\nx-giant    [NX Daemon Server] -
> 2022-12-24T22:56:37.037Z - [REQUEST]: Client Request for Project Graph
> Received    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.073Z - [REQUEST]:
> Updated file-hasher based on watched changes, recomputing project
> graph...    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.327Z - [REQUEST]:
> Responding to the client. project-graph    [NX Daemon Server] -
> 2022-12-24T22:56:37.331Z - Time taken for 'total for creating and
> serializing project graph' 289.47169998288155ms    [NX Daemon Server]
>
> - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.335Z - Closed a connection. Number of open connections: 1    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.335Z - Done
>   responding to the client project-graph    [NX Daemon Server] -
>   2022-12-24T22:56:37.614Z - Established a connection. Number of open
>   connections: 2    [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.614Z -
>   Established a   [NX Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.618Z -
>   [REQUEST]: Responding to the client. project-graph   [NX Daemon
>   Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.622Z - Time taken for 'total for
>   creating and serializing project graph' 0.30550000071525574ms    [NX
>   Daemon Server] - 2022-12-24T22:56:37.622Z - Done responding to the
>   client project-graph